# Нужно растянуть строку на заданное к-во символов

Tags: java

В общем дана какая-то строка с набором символов/слов, нужно растянуть ее, на заданную длину. Пока что все, на что я смог с себя выдавить так это вот такой "кострубатый" код.

```
    public static String stringAligning(String stringToAlign, int lengthAlignment) {
    String resultString = stringToAlign;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(resultString);

    int temp = 1;
    if (stringToAlign.length() < lengthAlignment) {
        while (sb.length() < lengthAlignment) {
            for (int i = 1; i < sb.length(); i += temp) {
                if (resultString.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                    sb.insert(i, ' ');
                    temp = 2;
                }else {
                    temp = 1;
                }

            }
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("lengthAlignment number is lower than line");
    }
    resultString = sb.toString();
    return resultString;
}
```

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то это процедура которая традиционно называется `pad`. Есть [несколько методов](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388461/5694145).

Comment: так там добавляют пробелы или символы после только 1 слова... а мне по сути нужно ставить после кожного слова по пробелу(цикл), если же в конце после посл. слова длина все же меньше заданного числа, цикл повторяем, пока условие не будет верным

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static String stringAligning(String stringToAlign, int lengthAlignment) {
    String fs = "%"+lengthAlignment+"s";
    return String.format(fs,stringToAlign);
}
```

Если длиннее - обрежет, если короче добавит.

В примере добавляются лидирующие пробелы. Для добавления пробелов в конец строки используйте `"%-"+lengthAlignment+"s"`.

Почитайте [о форматировании строк](http://study-java.ru/uroki-java/formatirovanie-chisel-i-texta-v-java/).

Хоть это и не правильно, но вот полное решение задачи по шагам.

```
    //Вводные данные
    String demo = "Пам парам     пам    пам     пурум"; //строка
    int strSize = 60; //длинна, на которую ее надо натянуть нормализовав пробелы

    //Разбиваем строку на массив слов.
    String[] norma = demo.split("\\s+");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(norma)); //[Пам, парам, пам, пам, пурум]

    //Вычисляем сумму символов всех слов 
    int chCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < norma.length; i++) {
        chCount += norma[i].length();
    }
    System.out.println("chCount=" + chCount); //chCount=19

    // Между N словами помещается N-1 пробел. Вычислим длинну "целого" пробела
    int padSize = (strSize - chCount)/(norma.length-1);
    System.out.println("padSize=" + padSize); //padSize=10

    //Кроме "целых" пробелов у нас останется запас.
    int spaces = (strSize - chCount)%(norma.length-1);
    System.out.println("spaces=" + spaces); //spaces=1

    //Формируем строку
    String result = norma[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < norma.length; i++) {
        //Слово + пробелы перед ним. Так как будем испльзовать String.format
        int pad = padSize+norma[i].length();
        //Если есть пробелы в запасе +1
        if (spaces>0) {
            pad = pad+1;
            spaces--;
        }
        String sf = "%" + pad + "s";
        result += String.format(sf,norma[i]);
    }
    //Итого
    System.out.println("123456789+123456789+123456789+123456789+123456789+123456789+");
    System.out.println(result);
    //123456789+123456789+123456789+123456789+123456789+123456789+
    //Пам           парам          пам          пам          пурум
```

Comment: String hexwad = "adwd dawdaw dawdaw fwafawfawfa";
        String hexrework = Util.stringAligning2(hexwad, 80);
        System.out.println(hexrework);
вывод дало "%s" и все

Comment: @user213177 Исправил ошибку. % перед s - лишний.

Comment: наверное достал уже вас, да?)
вы дали мне пример про растягивание строки, добавлением лидирующих или завершающих пробелов. Моя же задача состоит в том, чтобы сделать что-то типу такого "adwd(5 пробелов)dawdaw(5 пробелов)dawdaw(5 пробелов)fwafawfawfa(5 пробелов)"
С-венно с вашим примером мне сейчас пришла идея разбить строку на слова, потом с каждым провести этот фокус с добавлением пробелов, а потом назад сложить в строку...Как я это реализую еще хз, но может тоже есть функция наподобие этой, только в 1-2 строки?
Или вы мне ее собственно и дали, просто я из племени "тупа-тупа"?

Comment: @user213177 смотри обновление. Старайся разбивать задачу на мелкие вопросы и находить на них ответ. Удачи.